# approximation of a constant raised to a power that is less than one

Tags: convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients, taylor-expansion, approximation

Could anyone please help me approximate $\omega^\gamma$.

$\omega=2\pi f$. The range of $f$ is from $0.5 - 200$ and the range of $\gamma$ is from $0.5 - 1$. I tried it to convert to exponential and logarithm like $e^{\gamma log\omega}$ and then expanding it using $e^x$ expansion but I guess its not the best way.

The idea is to be able to approximate the final value with simple multiplications and divisions as I need to implement it on an embedded system.
Also, will it help to try to approximate it using binomial or Taylor expansion?

Comment: Your idea is fine: just take a Taylor expansion of the logarithm and a Taylor expansion of the exponential. You will need to do some playing around with the remainder theorems in order to know how many terms to take. It may or may not be faster to make the number of terms you use depend on the values of $\omega$ and $\gamma$, it depends on hardware specifics and such.

Answer (score 1):

Look up Cordic.

These methods were used in the 70s
to compute various functions.

Also,
search for
"Approximations for Digital Computers"
by Hastings.
This classic has approximations for,
among others,
$10^x$ and
$\log_{10} x$
which you might
be able to compose
to do your computions.